# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarView can only be used with android:layout_width="match_parent"

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

### Background

I use ActionBarSherlock since I wish to handle old Android versions, and since the official Google's library for old Android devices doesn't have some important classes (like the PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment, so that they will have an actionBar).

### The problem

Recently I got this weird exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarView can only be used with
>   android:layout_width="match_parent" (or fill_parent) at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.onMeasure(SourceFile:772)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onMeasure(SourceFile:181)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322) at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:876) at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1911) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And I can't find out why it occurs, as only a single user has reported it even though my app works fine on older Android versions (that I've tried).

### What I've tried

I've found [this post](https://github.com/frakbot/FWeather/issues/115), and they say they don't know how to fix it other than just ditching old Android versions...

### The question

Is it possible to fix this issue in some way? If so, how?

Will going to the official Google's library fix it somehow?

Comment: ABS is no longer maintained and it is highly recommended you move to AppCompat to use the actionbar. Since it is unknown as to what is causing the error it is also unknown as if moving to `AppCompat` will fix the problem. for all we know you could be doing something weird with your layouts

Comment: @tyczj I wrote that it works fine on all old Android versions I've tested, and that I use ABS because Google's library doesn't support PreferenceFragment and PreferenceActivity .

Comment: PreferenceFragment and PreferenceActivity was never in the support library you have to check what version the device has at runtime and either display a PreferenceActivity if < SDK 11 or show PreferenceFragment if > SDK 11

Comment: @tyczj PreferenceActivity is available from API 1 , but it isn't in the support library: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html . The reason I want to have it is that it allows to have an action bar there.

Comment: have a look at this library https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

Comment: `doesn't have some important classes (like the PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment).` PreferenceActivity is there since **always**, PreferrenceFragment is in the `support-library-v4`. ActionBarCompat is in the AppCompat library project (not to be included as jar, but to be referred as external library). Im using a PreferenceActivity for API Levels lower than 11 and for higher API Levels I switch to a PreferenceFragment. And I also can have an ActionBarCompat, without using the **no longer supported** ActionBarSherlock

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I know about PreferenceActivity (that it was there since API 1) and I also wrote about it, but it won't have the action bar on it, at least that's what I saw last time I've checked Google's libraries. Are you saying they've finally added an actionBar support for those classes?

Comment: I didn't realize that you wanted the **ActionBar OVER the PreferenceScreen** (really?), sorry.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein What do you mean "Over" ? the actionBar is supposed to be there. Just open any API 11 (and above) device that shows the PreferenceActivity and see for yourself - the actionBar will be shown at the top of the screen. It's the normal behavior. It would be weird to see the actionBar everywhere except there... Anyway, are you sure there is a PreferenceFragment somewhere in Google's libraries?

Comment: Well, I made an app which doesn't use an ActionBar (would you believe that?). I provide two "custom ActionBars" (top and bottom), which are simply a couple of RelativeLayouts and some controls inside (mostly clickable TextViews). I don't use them in the PreferenceActivity screen, nor in the PreferenceFragment screen. So I have them **full screen**

Comment: @FrankN.Stein ok, I guess it's time to check it out again... hope it will fix this issue.